# xamarin app to replace native android app on google play store

Tags: android, xamarin, app-store

i have an existing native android app on the google play store. We have now developed the same app in xamarin and wish to go ahead with the xamarin one here on. I need to understand if it is possible to now put the xamarin apk on the store in place of native android one so the user receives the xamarin app as an update and not as a new app? I want to xamarin version to go as update to the user. Please guide me with the steps that will need to be taken to do so.

Comment: Are you able to update the existing Native app with Xamarin update ? We are getting an issue, i.e. while updating the application from alpha it says "Can't install app" with error code 910. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to keep the package name and signing key you are able to deploy your app as an update to the user. Don't forget to bump up the version number.