# How to resolve "Can't Update the app(Error Code : 901)" error?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, release, app-update

I'm migrating one of my live applications from Native to Xamarin. I have successfully done that and now I'm trying to release the same on Google Play Store.

I have generated a release build for the same in Xamarin android. Following are the scenarios which will describe the issue I'm facing -

1. **Fresh Install** - As I have a release apk for my application, I'm able to install it on my device and it's working smoothly.
2. **Update Scenario** - As I have mentioned earlier that the application is already live which was developed on Native Android, I have installed the live version of the same and tried updating the app using the latest release build that I have generated from Xamarin. In this case I'm getting the issue. 
   Attached a screenshot for the reference.

**What I have tried so far to resolve the issue** -

As there are multiple questions related to this issue, I have tried following things to get rid of this issue -

- Clear data and Clear Cache of Google Play Store application.
- Checked the Signing keys are same as before.
- Checked the package name is same as before.
- Removed the Google account and added again as per the suggestions.

I need to resolve this error soon, so I can't use the Fresh Install technique as an option.

[image: Error Image Screenshot]

Comment: http://techdescribed.com/google-play-store-error-code-910/

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/204469/why-is-play-store-showing-cant-install-app-error-code-910

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I have already mentioned that I have tried clearing the cache and data for Play service and the other option is to uninstall the older version which I don't want so neither of them are helpful for me in this case.

Comment: A similar post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48882043/xamarin-app-to-replace-native-android-app-on-google-play-store?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

I am able to identify the issue and fortunate that it got resolved. Sharing it here so if anyone gets stuck for the same issue then they can refer this.

**Identified Issue -** The issue was quite silly as the version code wasn't getting updated from the UI of Android Manifest even if I was changing the values. That might be the glitch in Xamarin or Visual Studio (for Xamarin).

**What I did to resolve this -**  I manually deleted the declaration of Version Code and other values which weren't changing from AndroidManifest.xml then from the UI section of the Manifest I upgraded the Version Code and build the solution for release. That's how things got resolved at my end.

Hope this helps. Thanks.